# iPhone, sqlite3, how do detect a null date, getting error when assigning to a NSString?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

This is my code

```
NSString *enddate = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
```

I need to have null dates, but when a null is passed to this line, I get an error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot initialize `NSString` objects with a NULL pointer so just check for that condition:

```
const char* date = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
NSString *enddate = date == NULL ? nil : [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:date];
```